# Facebook Share success callback

Tags: facebook

Is there a callback or another way to track whether or not someone successfully shared something using the share button?

Comment: Are you using Facebook Graph API, The Legacy Facebook API for Facebook UI?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you using [FB.ui](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui)?

As it says right there in the docs

```
function(response) {
  if (response && response.post_id) {
    alert('Post was published.');
  } else {
    alert('Post was not published.');
  }
}
```

Comment: I was using the simple social plug in FBML code..I checked the JS SDK method u mentioned above and it seems great.. The only prob am seeing now is - if I use stream.share example its returning the response as undefined always ( http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?pid=252362 )..  strem.publish work excellent though.. can you plz tell me wat is the difference between those methods and is there any restriction in using strem.publish method.

Comment: We have implemented the stream.publis method successfully.. 

Thanks.